# upload and save an image from my android apps to my webserver

Tags: qml, qt6

want to upload to an image element and convert to blob before send to my API for saver to MySQL database

I want to save an image loaded from file-dialog and convert to blob before sending it to my API web-server for save to MySQL database qml qt6

this is my codes

```
 FileDialog {
            id: fileDialog
            nameFilters: ["Images (*.png *.jpg)"]
           // currentFolder: StandardPaths.standardLocations(StandardPaths.PicturesLocation)[0]
            onAccepted: {
                var fileUrl = fileDialog.currentFile
                if (fileUrl !== undefined) {
                    console.error("chemin:", fileUrl)
                    var localPath = fileUrl
                    var file = Qt.platform.file.exists(localPath)
                    if (file) {
                        var fileObj = Qt.platform.file.open(localPath, "r")
                        if (fileObj) {
                            var byteArray = fileObj.readAll()
                            fileObj.close()
                            var fileData = byteArray.toBase64()
                            console.error("chemin:", fileUrl)

                            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                            var url = "http://localhost:5000/upload_image";
                            xhr.open("POST", url, true);
                            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

                            var data = JSON.stringify({"image": fileData});
                            xhr.send(data);
                        }
                    } else {
                        console.error("Le fichier n'existe pas.")
                    }
                } else {
                    console.error("Le chemin du fichier n'est pas défini ou est vide.")
                }
            }
        }
```